# React: Unexpected token, expected "," inside JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
    return (
       <Header text='Web development curriculum' />
       {courses.map(course => 
         <Course key={course.id} course={course} />
       )}
    )
```

I'm getting SyntaxError Unexpected token, expected "," at the start of the inline javascript inside my JSX. Can't wrap my head around why.

Comment: You can't have two or more JSX elements next to each without a common parent. Wrap the code in a `div` or `React.Fragment`.

Comment: You are returning adjacent JSX elements which are not wrapped in a `<React.Fragment>` Wrap them in `<React.Fragment><Header ...>{courses.map(...)}</React.Fragment>`

Comment: Duplicate: [unexpected token, expected "," inside of react render() function in the return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56939549/unexpected-token-expected-inside-of-react-render-function-in-the-return-s)

Comment: Ohhhh.. I knew that, but for some reason didn't even think of it. The growing pains of learning React I guess haha. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap this code with some tags.
elements should have only one root element. and js code should be wrapped within tags.

```
 return (
      <>
       <Header text='Web development curriculum' />
       <div>
       {courses.map(course => 
         <Course key={course.id} course={course} />
       )}
       </div>
     </>
    )
```

Comment: This is a duplicate, as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can only have a single JSX element in brackets. Just like in regular JS you can't do `const number = (5 6)`. You could add a `,` in between, but this makes JS (and thus React) only pick the last JSX element. Use fragments instead:

```js
    return <>
       <Header text='Web development curriculum' />
       {courses.map(course => 
         <Course key={course.id} course={course} />
       )}
    </>;
```

*`<> </>` is short for `<React.Fragment> </React.Fragment>`.*

Comment: This is a duplicate, as expected